# Compiler Warning C4251: Problem exporting a class in a *.dll

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport, kinect

EDIT: Forgive my noobish-ness, I haven't ever implemented a wrapper .dll before! :S

I've been tinkering a bit with some of the recently released Kinect Sensor hacks (namely [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org) and [OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/)) and I'm now trying to wrap the functionality in a *.dll for use in various "test" programs that I hope to write.

So far I've set up a *.dll project and have got a lot of the library functionality in, however I'm getting C4251 compiler warnings all over the place.

In the project settings I've got the `OpenNI.lib` file statically linked, so far my library header looks like this:

```
#ifdef LIBKINECT_EXPORTS
#define LIBKINECT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIBKINECT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// This class is exported from the LibKinect.dll
class LIBKINECT_API CLibKinect
{
public:

    CLibKinect(void);
    ~CLibKinect(void);

    bool Init(void);

protected:

private:

    xn::Context                     m_xContext;
    xn::DepthGenerator              m_xDepthGen;
};
```

And my `stdafx.h` file contains:

```
#pragma once

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

#include <XnOpenNI.h>
#include <XnCodecIDs.h>
#include <XnCppWrapper.h>
```

Now I've attempted to create a windows console app to test the library and I get lots of `error C2653: 'xn' : is not a class or namespace name` errors. I was hoping that in the application I would only have to include and link to the wrapper *.dll not all of the OpenNI stuff as well, so as to hide the underlying implementation, is this incorrect?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

Comment: Have you done `#include "stdafx.h"` in the library header?

Comment: No it's in the `LibKinect.cpp` file as pre-compiled headers must be. I see where I'm going wrong; the fact that I have objects in the `xn::` namespace in the `LibKinect.h` file, which the client app then includes and has no idea what the hell `xn::` **is**. However, I'm still a little confused as to how best to fix this.

Comment: @Siyfion: Yeah..its not a good idea to put `stdafx.h` include in the header file. The simplest way to solve this is to use the pimpl idiom. Check here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom

Comment: Haha.. Funny that as I was just about to write "Hurrah! For I have found the way of the [Pimpl](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/sweet-snippets/the-c-pimpl-r1794)"

Comment: Asha, if you post that as an answer I'll mark it up! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to hide the fact you are using `xn` namespace in your implementation, you should not put that in the library header file. The simplest way to solve this problem is to use the [pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).